# how to store Uint8List in mysql

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, uint8list

I'm trying to store images in the database by converting them to Uint8List and then show images in flutter , I tried to store the Uint8List  as TEXT and as VARCHAR
and I have an error Expected value of type Uint8List  and got String

```
addimage(String x , Uint8List img)async{
    print (x);
    var url = 'http://ip/imageStore.php';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body :{
      'word': x,
      'imageByte': img,
    });



snapshot.data![index]['imageByte'] as Uint8List
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using base64 encoding and decoding then storing the encoded image as Text in mysql
and when i want to display my Image i used image.memory

```
       image = base64Encode(Uint8List_image); // convert image to base64 (String);
       image.memory(base64Decode(image)); // convert encoded image to Uint8List and display it ;
```

Comment: Do not store images as text, particularly not with base64 encoding! Use proper binary data type, like blob!